# Testing orchestrator azure durable functions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, azure-functions, nunit

I'm writing unit tests for our azure functions and I'm trying to figure out how to test that activities/sub-orchestration was called during the Orchestration run. I'm also not too sure what part of this orchestration for example should require testing ?

```cs
[FunctionName(nameof("Orchestrator"))]
    public static async Task Run(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(log);
        
        var completeProjectDto = context.GetInput<CompleteProjectDto>();
        try
        {
            var tasks= new List<Task>
            {
                context.CallActivityAsync(nameof("activity1"), inputObject),
                context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync(nameof("sub1"), inputObject),
                context.CallActivityAsync(nameof("activity3"), inputObject)
            };

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            await context.CallActivityAsync(nameof("activity4"), inputObject);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.LogError("Caught an error from an activity: {Message}", e.Message);
        }
    }
```

This is my test class I'm using nUnit.

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class Tests: UnitTestBase<Tests>
{
    private Mock<IDurableOrchestrationContext> durableOrchestrationContext;
    private Mock<ILogger> loggerMock;
    private InputObject inputObject;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        inputObject = new InputObject
        {
            param1 = 2,
            param2 = "G123DF",
            param3 = 2
        };

        durableOrchestrationContext = RegisterMock<IDurableOrchestrationContext>();
        loggerMock = RegisterMock<ILogger>();
    }
    [Test]
    public async Task WhenStartingOrchestration_ShouldCallActivitiesAndSubOrchestrator()
    {
        durableOrchestrationContext.Setup(x => x.CallActivityAsync<Task>(nameof("activity1" ), inputObject))
            .ReturnsAsync(It.IsAny<Task>());
        durableOrchestrationContext.Setup(x => x.CallSubOrchestratorAsync<Task>(nameof("sub1"), inputObject))
            .ReturnsAsync(It.IsAny<Task>());
        durableOrchestrationContext.Setup(x => x.CallActivityAsync<Task>(nameof("activity2"), inputObject))
            .ReturnsAsync(It.IsAny<Task>());
        
        durableOrchestrationContext.Setup(x => x.CallActivityAsync<Task>(nameof("activity3"), inputObject))
            .ReturnsAsync(It.IsAny<Task>());

        await Orchestrator.Run(durableOrchestrationContext.Object, loggerMock.Object);

        durableOrchestrationContext.Verify(m => m.CallActivityAsync<Task>(nameof("activity1"), inputObject), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

I think that since I'm awaiting all tasks here, there is probably some setup code that I'm missing. Should I await all tasks in my test class as I did in the main code? Also, the activities / sub-orchestration returns only a task nothing special.

I get this error :

```
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: m => m.CallActivityAsync<Task>("activity1", inputObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just by having a quick look I can tell that you mocked the wrong overload of `CallActivityAsync` method.
The one used in the orchestrator function is `CallActivityAsync(String, Object)` and the one in test's arrangement is `CallActivityAsync<TResult>(String, Object)`.

The latter should be used if a triggered activity function returns serializable result of `TResult` type.

So the correct setup should look something like this:

```
durableOrchestrationContext
    .Setup(x => x.CallActivityAsync(nameof("activity1" ), inputObject))
    .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

As to your other question:

> I'm also not too sure what part of this orchestration for example
> should require testing ?

Orchestrator function is where you put logic related to making business decissions. It should reflect system's business requirements and that's what should be tested.

E.g. (Orchestrator function) wait X days for customer's action and if the customer does not respond, then (Activity function) send him a reminder (Activity function).

The test for the example business rule should check if in case of timeout the activity function is called (and perhaps the complementary case).